# How to convert Scala trait to Java classes?

Tags: java, scala

I try to convert some Scala sources to Java sources. But I face some troubles. Below are the Scala sources.

```
trait Reader {
  def read(name: String): String = {
    //some codes are here.....
  }
}

trait FileInputBase {
  def getFormat(path: String): String = {
    //some codes are here.....
  }
}

case class FileStreamInput(name: String, path: String) extends Reader with FileInputBase {
  def read(name: String): String = {
    //some codes are here.....
  }

  var format = getFormat("joseph") 
}
```

I convert these Scala codes to Java sources like below,

```
class Reader {
  public String read(String name) {
    // some java codes are here
  }
}

interface FileInputBase {
  public String getFormat(String path) {
    // some java codes are here
  }
}
```

and I make the java class

```
public class FileStreamInput extends Reader implements FileInputBase {
  ....
}
```

But these Java codes are not working at all. I am a beginner of Scala language.

Comment: What is the error you're getting? By not working, what is the desired behavior of your program, could you update the question statement with that.

Comment: Also, as a side note, Scala traits are better viewed as Java interfaces. So, in your case making the Reader into an interface rather than a class will work better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
public interface Reader {

  default String read(String name) {
    return "reading from " + name;
  }

}

public interface FileInputBase {

  default String getFormat(String path) {
    return "Format of " + path;
  }

}


public class FileStreamInput implements Reader, FileInputBase {

  private String path;

  private String name;


  public FileStreamInput(String path, String name) {
    super();
    this.path = path;
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String read(String name) {
    return "FileStreamInput: reading from " + name;
  }

  public String getPath() {
    return path;
  }

  public void setPath(String path) {
    this.path = path;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getFormat() {
    return getFormat(path);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    FileStreamInput input = new FileStreamInput("Alice", "/home/alice");
    System.out.println("format: " + input.getFormat());
  }

}
```